# Как открыть background-image в popup

Tags: javascript, background, popup

Есть подобная HTML-разметка.
Блок, у него задан background-image через динамический `style=""`.
Как открыть `background-image` в popup?

```
<div class="uk-cover-background uk-position-cover" style="background-image: url(/images/odjects/342.jpg;);"></div>
```

Comment: Что динамичного в подобном style? :)

Comment: 2 заметки: 1) url(/images/odjects/342.jpg); и 2) вы пытаетесь вставить bg картинку отдельным div'ом? Из вашего вопроса ничего не понятно